# wordpress redirect is not working via form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have created custom form in footer.php and in form action I have placed action=" and when I submit the form data is saving perfectly but i do not know how come when form is submitted it comes up with blog page as of the link url remain same but do not know why it comes up with blogpage can anyine help me out with this concern please

```
<form class="booking-form" method="POST" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>
                Name
            </h5>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>
                Phone
            </h5>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>
                Address
            </h5>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="address"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>
                Date
            </h5>
            <input type="text" class="form-control date_of_event" name="date_of_event" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>
                Type
            </h5>
            <input type="text" class="form-control type_agent" name="type" value="">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" name="create_new_event" class="btn btn-block">Create Event</button>
    </form>
```

This is the header.php

```
global $wpdb;

if(isset($_REQUEST['create_new_event'])) {
    $data = array(
        "name"    => $_REQUEST['name'],
        "phone"   => $_REQUEST['phone'],
        "address" => $_REQUEST['address'],
        "date"    => $_REQUEST['date_of_event'],
        "type"    => $_REQUEST['type'],
        "status"  => 'booked'
    );

    $new  = $wpdb->insert("wp_events", $data);
    wp_redirect(get_permalink());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need exit after redirect.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/

`wp_redirect( $url );
exit;`

Comment: This domainname.com page can’t be found this error comes up

Comment: You may use var_dump(get_permalink()); try add <input name='_ref' value='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'> and use: $_REQUEST['_ref']